# Using intnx to get the same date last year in SAS

Tags: sas

I want to pull the same date one year before my variable 'day_3_ago'

My code:

```
%macro date; 
data _null_;
call symput ('day_3_ago', put(intnx('day',today(),-3, 'b'),yymmddn8.));
run;
%mend;

%date;

%let last_year_3dayago = [1 year before day_3_ago]
```

For example, if I ran this code today, day_3_ago would be 20170624. I would want last_year_3dayago to be 20160624

My current solution is:

```
%let last_year_3daygo = %sysfunc(intnx(day,%sysfunc(inputn(&day_3)ago.,yymmdd8)),-365),yymmddn8);
```

but that doesn't account for leap years.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `intnx` with `day`, use `year` and end the function with `s` (or `same`) instead of `b`.

```
data _null_;
x = intnx('year',today()-3,-1,'s');
putlog x :date9.;
run;
```

Comment: You're right; but I would add some explanation to what the OP is doing wrong (why `year` is right and not `day`) and what `s` vs `b` does.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, there is also the option of manually changing the date for day_3_ago, so I want last_year_3dayago to always be 1 year before day_3_ago. Would that work?

Comment: You can substitute 'today-3' with "&day_3_ago"d in the function, but I believe it will need to be formatted as 'date9' instead of 'yymmdd8.'. I haven't got SAS available to check right now

Answer (score 0):

I modified Longfish's code to solve your requirement with the variable `last_year_3dayago`:

```
%let last_year_3dayago = 20170624;
data _null_;
  x = intnx('year',input("&last_year_3dayago.",b8601da.),-1,'s');
  putlog x :date9.;
run;
```